# cant upload a .webm file after recording

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, ffmpeg

I kinda seem to stuck on something. I am missing something i dont know. I have uploaded a lot of files but somehow when i recorded this file via my laptop camera browser and try to upload it.. it doesnt.. I am also using ffmpeg to convert it.

Laravel 5.4
vuejs
ffmpeg

These are the tools involved the error i am getting is the file doesnt exist in local temp folder.  ( i have checked it IS NOT there i dont understand why )

This is the code i am using :

```
        $input = $request->only('video' , 'url' , 'blob');
    $input['file'] =$request->file('blob');

    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
        'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe'
    ]);
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($input['file']);
    $video
        ->filters()
        ->resize(new Dimension(320, 240))
        ->synchronize();
    $video
        ->frame(TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
        ->save('frame.jpg');
    $video
        ->save(new Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
        ->save(new Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
        ->save(new Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');
```

This is the error :

> Unable to probe C:\Users\KAZMI\AppData\Local\Temp\php4155.tmp
>
> ffprobe failed to execute command "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe" C:\Users\KAZMI\AppData\Local\Temp\php4155.tmp -show_streams -print_format json

and this is the input data :

```
array:4 [  "video" => "video_7192228.webm"  "url" => "blob:http://localhost:8080/c319e0bf-7217-4916-90b6-c9cba800b7da"  "blob" => UploadedFile {#421    -test: false    -originalName: "blob"    -mimeType: "video/webm"    -size: 0    -error: 0    #hashName: null    path: "C:\Users\KAZMI\AppData\Local\Temp"    filename: "php8B7D.tmp"    basename: "php8B7D.tmp"    pathname: "C:\Users\KAZMI\AppData\Local\Temp\php8B7D.tmp"    extension: "tmp"    realPath: "C:\Users\KAZMI\AppData\Local\Temp\php8B7D.tmp"    aTime: 2017-10-14 14:20:24    mTime: 2017-10-14 14:20:24    cTime: 2017-10-14 14:20:24    inode: 0    size: 0    perms: 0100666    owner: 0    group: 0    type: "file"    writable: true    readable: true    executable: false    file: true    dir: false    link: false    linkTarget: "C:\Users\KAZMI\AppData\Local\Temp\php8B7D.tmp"  }  "file" => UploadedFile {#421}]
```